# Autonumeric not working with Parsley

Tags: javascript, parsley

I am using auto numeric plugin for currency input fields.

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Principal, new { @class = "form-control money", @required = "required",  @data_parsley_min = "1", @data_parsley_errors_messages_disabled="" })
```

In the above field I am using class money on which autonumeric is applied. Now if I remove the money class parsley validation works but it does not work if autonumeric is applied. Please help me in this regard

Comment: What you mean by "autonumeric is applied"?

Comment: autonumeric plugin is initialized on this input field with the selector class money

Comment: Please provide a live reproducible test case to help up help you.